# _yylval is a unresolved external symbol

Tags: c, lex, flex-lexer

First of all. I am new to flex/lex. So this could be a easy question for you guys or hard because i dont know where the problem is directly.

My Code:

```
    /* example.lex */
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "global.h"
extern int yylval;   
%}

%option noyywrap

delim     [\t\n]
ws        [\t\n]+
letter    [A-Za-z]
digit     [0-9]
id        {letter}({letter}|{digit})*
nummer    [0-9]+

%%

{ws}       { /* Dont Do Anything */ }
{id}       { yylval = atoi(yytext); return ID; }
{nummer}   { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUM; }
"+"        { return '+'; }
"-"        { return '-'; }
"*"        { return '*'; }

%%
```

This is everything that my example.lex file has. Let me know if you need more information.
Any tips/help on what i should try to fix this problem is welcome

Comment: Are you using yacc/bison for your parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yylval` is usually defined by bison (yacc). If you are not using bison, then you need to define `yylval` yourself.

In your case, if you are not using bison, you can simply remove the "extern" from the `llval` definition you have. If you use `yylval` in another file, you will have to declare it "extern" in that file.

If you are using yacc, you need to #include "y.tab.h" in your lex file. You can create y.tab.h by running `'bison -d file.y'`.

---

If you are looking for a very simple answer, then change:

```
extern int yylval;
```

to

```
int yylval;
```